# Control fans speed relative to higher temperature

Tags: fan, temperature, speedfan

Hi guys:)I want to control my fans' speed relative to the higher temperature that a component has in the pc.Is it possible to do?Is it a good idea?

Comment: Can you provide your operating system, your motherboard model (or make + model of laptop if applicable), and any potential solutions you have already explored?

Comment: I am going to buy an asus maximus viii hero with windows 10.I have tried nothing because fro me it is the first time

Answer (score 0):

On an ASUS Maximus VIII HERO you will be able to set custom fan logic through the UEFI BIOS. When booting up, spam `F9` a bunch before you get to your Windows loading screen, this should put you into the motherboard setup screen ("basic input/output system" or BIOS for short).

Poke around and look for fan controls. If you do not know what a setting does, it is wise not to change it without research into safe/compatible settings.

edit: your motherboard likely does this by default

Addtl info:

For much more granular, customizable, and robust control you can use an app like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) which allows for the ability to influence the speed of a fan given the temperature(s) of sensors other than those natively associated with the fan that is plugged into that header.

Comment: Yes but it does what I have asked?Does it set fans' speed relative to the higher temperature of the system?

Comment: Yes, it should have a graph that maps fan speed in RPM to CPU temperature. Most of them typically have a way to add points and create a curve along which the fan speed will change per temperature.

Comment: Something very similar to this: http://images.anandtech.com/doci/9729/ASUS170A%20BIOS%2007%20-%20Q-Fan.jpg

Comment: No,i am thinking another thing.For example:I have 5 thermal sensors,I want that fan's speed will be controlled relative to  the higher temperature that is detected from those thermal sensors

Comment: So you have 5 thermal sensors - are these external and plugged into the computer somehow?

Comment: The asus maximus viii hero has some thermal sensors and the possibility to install some others.I want to set fans' speed from those

Comment: There should be 3-4 pin fan headers on the motherboard, each will be labelled e.g. `SYS` `CH1` `CH2` etc. Look at the left-hand side of the picture in the earlier comment - this should allow you to set custom fan settings per header.

Comment: I have understood this but I don't need to know how to set every fan.I need to know how to set the fans relative to the higher temperature of the system.For example if the cpu has the higher temperature all the fans will be set relative to that temperature, if after 10 seconds the gpu's temperature becomes higher than cpu's so all the fans will be adapted to that temperature...

Comment: So you want all fans to react identically to the variable average of all temperature probes?

Comment: Yes,I want that all fans will react identically based on higher temperature that is detected

Comment: Added more info to the bottom of my answer